# Passing checkbox values to php - missing values

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, multidimensional-array

I am having an issue where we cannot join up our checkboxes with the other fields being passsed.

If we only check the second checkbox it will take the value of the first row select box.

The rows are joined up by the date e.g.2014-06-02, 2014-06-03

HTML

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="date_choice[]" value="2014-06-02">
 <select id="event_start" name="event_start[2014-06-02][]"    onchange="area_choice_click()">
 <option value="">Start Time</option>
 <option value="01:00">1.00AM</option>
 <option value="02:00">2.00AM</option>
 <option value="03:00">3.00AM</option>

 </select>
 <select id="event_end" name="event_end[2014-06-02][]" onchange="area_choice_click()">
 <option value="">End Time</option>
 <option value="01:00">1.00AM</option>
 <option value="02:00">2.00AM</option>
 <option value="03:00">3.00AM</option>
 </select> 



   <input type="checkbox" name="date_choice[]" value="2014-06-03">
 <select id="event_start" name="event_start[2014-06-03][]"        onchange="area_choice_click()">
 <option value="">Start Time</option>
 <option value="01:00">1.00AM</option>
 <option value="02:00">2.00AM</option>
 <option value="03:00">3.00AM</option>
 </select>


 <select id="event_end" name="event_end[2014-06-03][]" onchange="area_choice_click()">
 <option value="">End Time</option>
 <option value="01:00">1.00AM</option>
 <option value="02:00">2.00AM</option>
 <option value="03:00">3.00AM</option>
 </select>
```

PHP

```
  foreach($_POST['date_choice'] as $key=>$team_id){

 $event_date = $_POST['date_choice'][$key]; 

  echo"$event_date";

  $event_start=$_POST['event_start'][$event_date][$key]; 

 }
```

Comment: If a checkbox isn't checked it won't appear in the post data. The absence of a key in your array tells you that it was unchecked. (kinda weird if you ask me, but that's how it's designed)

Comment: the problem is it still passes the other values e.g. select box and input type, how can i link them up together?